# URL in Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, url

How do I get an URL in Unity Launcher, so when I click the URL the website of that URL opens in my standard webbrowser - i.e. firefox. (I am using Ubuntu 12.10)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xdg-open`:

Run `gksudo gedit` to get a root text editor, and paste:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=xdg-open [URL HERE]
Name=[NAME HERE]
Comment=[COMMENT/TOOLTIP HERE]
Icon=[ICON HERE]
```

You can look for icons in `/usr/share/pixmaps`

Save the file in `/usr/share/applications/`, and logoff and logon for good measure. Search for the launcher by name withing the Unity dash and drag it to the launcher.