# Custom launcher arguments?

Tags: unity, launcher

I know I can add [custom shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher) or even [url links](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207634/url-in-launcher) to the launcher.

Can I create custom launcher shortcuts that accept or process arguments?

For example, can I set a launcher link to open `http://google.com/#q=%s`, so that when I type `google cat videos` in launcher, it will open the link replacing `%s` with `cat videos`?

Comment: No, that's not possible on Unity. The closest thing would be the remote scopes (in the example you give), but not the same in the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How about making new command `google`:

   `sudo nano /usr/bin/google`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   for w in $@ ; do query=$query+$w; done
   xdg-open http://google.com/#q=$query
   ```

   Add executing permission:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/google
   ```
2. To use it, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to open command launcher:

   ```
   google ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks; this suits my needs too. Two suggestions: it should be `query="$query $w"`, and it's best to surround the argument with quotes i.e. `xdg-open "http://google.com/#q=$query"`

Comment: @congusbongus, I tried that before and retried after you mentioned it. I couldn't get it to work, `xdg-open` keep spliting it on multiple calls. May be we have different versions (1.1.0~rc1-2u on Ubuntu 14.04). BTW, manual make it clear the parameter should be a File or URL. So It should be encoded.

Comment: @congusbongus, if that way (ie with space) works for you, then you call simply `xdg-open "http://google.com/#q=$@"` no need for that loop/variable indeed I added them basically to fix that behavior (splitting call commands at space) in my case.